# Is there a way to get the database location from a sqlite3 object?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have a bunch of sqlite db's floating around in my app (dont ask) and I need to be able to get the file location of the dbs. Is there any way of doing this by using the sqlite3 object? (I.e. not having to store the path alongside the db when the db was created)

Bonus Question: If there are more than one db attached to the sqlite3 object, how do I get the others as well (they were ATTACHed)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

API function: [`sqlite3_db_filename`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_filename.html)

Comment: Anyone that is able to use this function? It isn't working for me.

Comment: @ceccoemi check your sqlite version

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 supposed to be opaque structure, but check SQLite headers, maybe you'll be find some undocumented fields there that contain the path to the database.

Even if you find such a field, using it is bad idea and will lead to maintenance issues sooner or later.

Why do you need to keep path to the database along with the handle, first of all?

Comment: There are many reasons: 1. It allows me to move the database elsewhere 2. I can check that I am not reopening the same database twice 3. I can check that a database that I might be overriding (when moving another database) isnt open, etc.

Comment: Why not to create something like a ConnectionPool then? A singleton that allows to pass path to database and get the handle back. Internally, that object could store the mapping between path and handle in a map. This way all the logic would be encapsulated in one place, and you would not rely on sqlite3 internals.

Comment: It adds an extra layer of complexity that I was hoping is unnecessary. Obviously this would be the way to do it if sqlite itself doesnt provide a method, but I was hoping that they did.

Comment: There's no problem with having the database open twice _from different threads_.

Answer (score -1):

Use filemon/processmon to monitor which files are being accessed by your app/process. You will find your SQLite file.